# Using xsd.exe with www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/?

Tags: xml, xsd.exe

Is there a possibility to use the Visual Studio tool xsd.exe together with a xsd scheme using the [www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) namespace? When I'm trying this I always get an error message:
Schema validation warning: The root element of a W3C XML schema must be  and its namespace must be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'. (Error message translated with deepl, the original error message is in German: Schemavalidierungswarnung: Das Stammelement eines W3C XML-Schemas muss  und sein Namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' lauten.)
I'm using the version 4.7.3081.0 of xsd.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means what it says. If it doesn't use the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` then it's not an XSD schema.

The URI `www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/` is the location of the XSD 1.1 specification. I don't know what made you think you could use it as a namespace.

The Microsoft XSD processor has not been upgraded to support XSD 1.1, and no amount of fiddling with namespaces will change that. The only XSD 1.1 processor I know of that runs on .NET is my own processor, Saxon.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I half expected it.
Can your processor generate c# classes aut of a xsd file?

Comment: No, the Saxon schema processor doesn't do data binding.